# how to install x11_xt_lib when configure VTK?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, x11, vtk

when I configure VTK with ccmake command on Ubuntu 14.04,
the following error message happens after I press c button.
how to install that stuff?

```
 CMake Error at Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeLists.txt:304 (message):
   X11_Xt_LIB could not be found.  Required for VTK X lib.
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libxt-dev` then rerun CMake?

Comment: On CentOS and RHEL just run 'yum install libXt-devel'

Comment: You can also just install VTK from `apt`.

Answer (score 27):

Try to install **libxt-dev** using:

```
sudo apt-get install libxt-dev
```

This is from http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/cmake-error-when-building-vtk-6-0-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-td5722859.html.

And at least it works for me, and my OS version is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: To compile VTK you will probably have to install  `libglew-dev` too (but the error should appear before `X11_Xt`). Note this is unrelated to `libxt-dev`